MAVROS arm64 Docker build
I am currently working on a project that is building MAVROS from source (for various reasons) for a Docker image, targeting arm64 systems using GitHub Actions. Due to long compilation times, we are observing that the job times out (the timeout for GitHub Actions jobs is 6 hours for GitHub hosted runners). A local test indicates that the image build time for arm64 systems takes ~9 hours total. Upon further inspection, we found that compiling the mavros_msgs package is the primary bottleneck (other than using QEMU) in the build as shown below:



Package
amd64 bare metal
amd64
arm64




mavlink
1.95s
2.14s
3min 46s


libmavconn
8.73s
9.00s
2min 14s


mavros_msgs
1min 25s
1min 27s
2h 56min 31s


mavros
1min 15s
1min 17s
16min 59s


mavros_extras
1min 1s
1min 2s
13min 46s


Total
3min 42s
3min 46s
3h 27min 25s



This seems to be a consequence of time spent running rosidl_generator, which has been mentioned in this question. I am wondering if there are any steps/optimizations that we could apply to help improve build times here? Below are the relevant steps from the Dockerfile that we are currently using:
# Manually install MAVROS from source
WORKDIR $USER_WORKSPACE/src/
ARG MAVROS_RELEASE=ros2
ARG ROS_DISTRO=jazzy
ARG MAVLINK_RELEASE=release/rolling/mavlink
RUN git clone --depth 1 -b ${MAVROS_RELEASE} https://github.com/mavlink/mavros.git
RUN git clone --depth 1 --recursive -b ${MAVLINK_RELEASE} https://github.com/mavlink/mavlink-gbp-release.git mavlink

# Build the workspace
RUN . "/opt/ros/${ROS_DISTRO}/setup.sh" \
    && colcon build

Note that this is duplicate, which I first posted the ArduPilot forums here
